# How do I use JCL after installing

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, jedi

I have just installed JCL  v2.4.1.4571 in D2009 (using the Install.bat file) from http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JEDI_Code_Library

There was a lot of 'progress activity' in the installation screen so I guess all went well.

My question is how do I use this newly installed JCL?

I found some .pas files in the ..\source\common folder I used for expanding the downloaded jcl-2.4.1.4571.zip file into. One .pas file is JclDateTime.pas and it contains the 'dates and times' routines. So I guess I can just search through this file for a routine I may want, but maybe there is a more streamlined way of finding routines?

Also any hints on using JCL in the IDE itself? I did not get much help asking google.

cheers

Comment: Refer to the JCL documentation to see what it can do for you. Surely something inspired you to install it in the first place, right?

Comment: <  Surely something inspired you to install it in the first place, right? > Yes, code donated by other Delphi users. Since I'm starting out I might learn something from people more learned than myself

Comment: < Refer to the JCL documentation to see what it can do for you> If I have to goto http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:JCL_Packages, http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:JCL_Functions and then http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:DayOfTheYear@TDateTime - no problem. thanks for your help

Comment: I was shocked/amazed/bit angered to get a -2 (within a very short time) next to my first ever question here. The question showed I had done some research (a blind man can see that) but 2 persons decided differently. What a lovely welcome to http://stackoverflow.com. I did get a very good response from Graymatter so that was good.
I did some research and found http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/251842#251842. This helped to explain the mindset here, especially Chris Marie answer at Apr 26 at 3:31

Comment: Your research simply wasn't on the problem's subject.

Comment: @Free <Your research simply wasn't on the problem's subject> How do you know? You are not sitting next to me. Have you made that assumption from what I have supplied? Should I have declared every dead-end I landed on? so as to appease whoever? I am just glad Graymatter wasn't judgemental and made the effort to supply a supportive answer. Geez so much bandwidth wasted on negativity. I can see where you guys are coming from, but when someone is joining the group (and asking their first question) you have to cut them some slack, at least in my world you do. (getting off my soap box now)

Comment: Ofc, you didn't do any research [on the right subject]. Otherwise you wouldn't miss an essential part of product.

Comment: @Tom: Welcome to StackOverflow. Might I suggest (since this is by your own admission this is your first ever question here) that you take a much less confrontational tone with people? You're the one asking people to volunteer **their time** to answer **your questions** and help solve **your problems**, after all. How to use code-based units is basic Delphi knowledge, and has nothing to do with the JCL at all. As far as "we have to cut you slack", frankly no we don't. It's your responsibility to write the question, not ours, and yours to provide the information; you're asking for help.

Comment: @Ken: Looks like I have ruffled some feathers with my petty question. I was not aware this was an elitist group. I thought it was just like any other forum where you asked a question and if someone was kind enough to answer, they did. I was also not aware of users being able to degrade the questioner because they think the question is not up to their standard. Also, <You're the one asking people to volunteer their time> - NO I'm not asking people to do anything; if you don't like the question 'move along nothing to see here'. Maybe the detractors can learn from the actions of Graymatter

Comment: @Tom: You most certainly **did** ask for our free help, by the very fact you posted your question here. If you don't like the standards, feel free to ask for a refund of your membership fees, and take your questions elsewhere. The [help] explains very clearly how this site works; if you don't like the guidelines or standards, there are many other sites you can post your questions. If you're going to stay here, my advice is to lose the attitude very quickly. Rude behavior and remarks discourage people from helping, and repeated poor behavior can cause suspension of your account here.

Comment: (continued) And one of the standards here (and the one you got the downvotes for) is that you're expected to do **basic research** yourself before posting here, and that includes **reading the documentation** and **looking at the sample code** that you already have, like that included with the JCL. If you can't be bothered to do that research, don't expect us to do it for you.

Comment: @Ken: Oh.. someone 'has a bee in their bonnet'. Please refrain from using BOLD, I find it offensive. Maybe some people need to read the 'help center' to learn how to express themselves in a more appropiate manner. Also maybe some people need to 'get off their high horse'.

Comment: @Tom: Fine. You don't want to hear constructive advice to improve your chances of getting help here. **Fine with me.** Continue being rude, acting juvenile, and getting downvotes on your questions. It's you that's being hurt (by not getting the help you need). Not me. Good luck.

Comment: If you had not selected the correct answer i would have answered it. No question is a bad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as an answer because it's too big for comments.

http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JEDI_Code_Library - "The JEDI Code Library (JCL) consists of a set of thoroughly tested and fully documented utility functions and non-visual classes". It's a code library. There are only a couple of things that plug into the IDE like JclDebug. You won't get much help from google because you don't use it in the IDE. You include the Jcl.... files in your source code and you can then use the functions.

A good starting point is the help files.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/files/JCL%20Releases/JCL%202.6%20Build%205178/jcl-2.6.0.5178-chmhelp.zip/download

or for the PDF file

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/files/JCL%20Releases/JCL%202.6%20Build%205178/jcl-2.6.0.5178-pdf.zip/download

Don't confuse the JCL with the JVCL. The first is a non-visual classes and utility functions, the second is a component library that plugs into the IDE.

Comment: Thanks Graymatter. Couple of GREAT tips like <It's a code library. There are only a couple of things that plug into the IDE like JclDebug. You include the Jcl.... files in your source code and you can then use the functions.> Have a great day.